# Orthogonal set proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Isn't this just the definition of an orthogonal set? What needs to be done to actually prove this?

Comment: The point is that it is sufficient to prove orthogonality for a basis, rather than for every vector in the subspace

Answer (score 1):

The definition of an **orthogonal complement** likely did not contain the word "basis". So you need to show that:
$$
\langle z, w \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } w \in W \iff \langle z, v \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } v \in \beta
$$
Now since $\beta \subseteq W$, the $\implies$ direction follows immediately. The converse isn't too hard to prove either; just apply the linear properties of the inner product.